# numba doesn't compile nested list comprehensions

Tags: python, numpy, numba, jit

I'm trying to reorder an array of shape `(a, b, c, c)` to shape `(b, a, c, c)`. So the new array would consist of `b`stacks, ordered '`a`-wise'. Here's my code:

```
@njit(locals={'out': float64[:, :, :, :], 'write_list': float64[:, :, :, :]})
def prepare_write(prep: ndarray):

    bands, years, width, height = prep.shape

    #   according to docs, nested "array comprehension" are supported...

    out = np.array([[prep[b][i] for b in range(bands)] for i in range(years)])
    # for i in range(years):
    #     out[i] = np.array([write_list[b][i] for b in range(bands)])
    for v in out:
        vote(v)
    return out
```

`vote` is just a (jitted) function that modifies the arrays in-place and shouldn't cause any trouble. Numba version is 0.55.1. The compiler complains:

```
 >>> setitem(array(undefined, 1d, C), int64, array(float64, 2d, C))
 
There are 16 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 16 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'setitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
    With argument(s): '(array(undefined, 1d, C), int64, array(float64, 2d, C))':
   No match.
```

With some trying out I understood that `setitem` is called inside the list comprehensions. So, how can I make this work and what exactly is the compiler's problem?

Comment: Maybe a naive question, can't you just use [`np.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that actually helped. I was suspecting there might be a `numpy` alternative but I'm not too versed into numpy and couldn't find any solution quickly. Also, there are some functions in the program that are not easily vectorized using numpy so my mind was already set on `numba`. I'll use your approach `np.transpose(x, (1, 0, 2, 3))` but I'd still wanna know why the above doesn't compile. Thanks again (and no, it's not naive at all)

Comment: `np.array([[prep[b][i] for b in range(bands)] for i in range(years)])` is really inefficient. You should clearly avoid this. Lists of lists are slow (much slower than 2D arrays). They are not contiguously stored in memory and list are also slower than array because of a different internal implementation (eg. designed to grow) and checks. `prep[b][i]` is also less efficient than `prep[b,i]`. Using Numba do not ensure high-performance if the code itself is inefficient. Note that `np.transpose` do not perform an eager transposition (it returns a transposed view) so a copy is required to do that.

Comment: Besides, the problem you have is certainly due to the type of the list of list not being properly inferred (hence the `undefined`). Creating an array and filling it generally solve this and is far more efficient.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the docs stated that no intermediary lists will be generated when using an 'array comprehension' that's why I wasn't too concerned. I also tried an approach with creating `out` beforehand as an empty array but that didn't work either. My problem is now solved anyway but with your insights, I might still get the other version to work, for educational purposes. Thanks!